# How to set Tomcat's "reloadable" flag in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, configuration

I am developing a web application in Spring Boot, and deploy it on a Tomcat 8.5 running on Windows. The issue I am facing is that Tomcat periodically produces very high CPU load due to Catalina checking if the app needs reloading. According to the [Tomcat 8 documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/loader.html), there is a `reloadable` flag that can be set to `false` for an application to disable this behaviour. Here's what the documentation says (emphasis is mine):

> Set to true if you want Catalina to monitor classes in
>   /WEB-INF/classes/ and /WEB-INF/lib for changes, and automatically
>   reload the web application if a change is detected. This feature is
>   very useful during application development, but it requires
>   significant runtime overhead and is not recommended for use on
>   deployed production applications. You can use the Manager web
>   application, however, to trigger reloads of deployed applications on
>   demand.
>
> **NOTE - The value for this property will be inherited from the
>   reloadable attribute you set on the surrounding Context component, and
>   any value you explicitly set here will be replaced.**

The question is: how do I set this particular `reloadable` flag to `false` in Spring Boot? Preferably without resorting to a manually created `META-INF/context.xml`, I am using annotations for configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by creating an [EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer.html)

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer configurableEmbeddedServletContainer) {
            if (configurableEmbeddedServletContainer instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
                ((TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) configurableEmbeddedServletContainer).addContextCustomizers(
                        new TomcatContextCustomizer() {
                            @Override
                            public void customize(Context context) {
                                context.setReloadable(false);
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit worried about the "embedded" part. Will this work even when running on a regular Tomcat?

Comment: No, this will not work for what Spring Boot calls *traditional deployment*. If you're creating a pure non-executable WAR package, you will have to "customize" the context the old fashioned way via the `META-INF/context.xml` file.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification! I'll stick to the `context.xml` then.